# Setting jpg to bitmap in a TgraphicControl

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Trying to add a background image to a TGraphicControl.

TCard(TGraphicControl)

```
Private
  BitMap1:TBitMap;       {Used to store a card image}
Public
  procedure SetBitmap(image: TBitmap);
```

......

```
 procedure TCard.SetBitmap(image: TBitmap);
 begin
   bitmap1 := Tbitmap.create();
   bitmap1.Assign(image);
   canvas.draw(0,0,bitmap1);
 end;
```

On Form 1 button click , I want to add the image to the tcard component

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  image : Tbitmap;
  jpg: TJpegImage;
begin
  image := TBitmap.create();
  jpg := Tjpegimage.Create();
  jpg.LoadFromFile(dir+'\pics\backcard.jpg');
  image.Assign(jpg);
  card1.setbitmap(image);
  card1.Repaint;
  image.Destroy;
  jpg.Destroy;
 end;
```

When I run this nothing happens. How do I get this image to the background of the TCard component?

Comment: Your `SetBitmap` code does nothing but create a bitmap and assign something to it. What is `bitmap1`, where is it declared, and what does it do? You've not included any of that information. Also, assuming that `bitmap1` is a property of `TCard`, what happens to any previous content it contained?

Comment: bitmap1 is declared up top, as a private of the TCard. I dont know how to set it to the background of the Tcard. Right now it does nothing but like you said. just assigns it to the bitmap1.

Comment: i have tried messing around with canvas.draw, but did not think it was the right direction. So left it out example after it assigns bitmap1 i tried stuff like `canvas.draw(0,0,bitmap1);`

Comment: You have to actually draw the bitmap once it's assigned, using a method of the control's `Canvas` like `Draw` or `StretchDraw` (or simply have your `TCard` contain a `TImage` and assign the bitmap to that instead, and let the `TImage` handle drawing it). It doesn't just magically appear on screen because you declared a bitmap. :-) (Just for the record: I'm not the one that downvoted your question. I just asked for clarification in a comment.)

Comment: @kenwhite yes i tried canvas draw, still no luck. if i add TImage would that not be just extra code where canvas can all ready do it? meh downvote..also ill add the canvas draw code i removed before posting

Comment: Yes, the `TCanvas` can do it. You're missing a lot of information in your question, though. Where are you setting the `Width` and `Height` of your control (so that there's actually room on the canvas to draw the image)? Where are you putting the `Draw` attempt?

Comment: currently not setting it, just when i drop the component. i have the width / height big enough to support the image.

Comment: What you need to understand is that controls do not maintain graphical representations of themselves. Instead they draw themselves when they are asked to. In Windows that's all driven by `WM_PAINT` messages. I recommend reading Petzold's book to firm up your understanding of this.

Comment: @Glen, if you would like to have more flexible graphic object for your component, give a try to `TPicture`, just like `TImage` does. You can add to your background image better format flexibility, because then would be enough to add e.g. `JPEG` unit to the `uses` clause and call `LoadFromFile` passing a path to the JPEG file. Or e.g. by adding `PngImage` to the uses clause, you can add PNG format support for it. For an example, take a look at [`this code`](http://pastebin.com/vwNuZ7fk). It includes also examples of how to load images.

Comment: thanks TLama Great example in that code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of setting a background image for a `TGraphicControl` descendant, and an example of using it (it uses a `TBitmap` in the form's `OnCreate`, and a `TJpegImage` in the `Button1Click` to demonstrate both). It requires nothing but a new blank VCL forms application with a single `TButton` located on it to start.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Jpeg, StdCtrls;

type
  TCard = class(TGraphicControl)
  private
    FBackGround: TBitmap;
    procedure SetBackground(Value: TBitmap); overload;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Paint; override;
  published
    property BackGround: TBitmap read FBackGround write SetBackground;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FCard: TCard;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TCard }

constructor TCard.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FBackGround := TBitmap.Create;
end;

destructor TCard.Destroy;
begin
  FBackground.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TCard.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  Self.Canvas.StretchDraw(Self.ClientRect, FBackGround);
end;

procedure TCard.SetBackground(Value: TBitmap);
begin
  FBackGround.Assign(Value);
  //Self.SetBounds(Left, Top, FBackGround.Width, FBackGround.Height);
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Image: TJPEGImage;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Image := TJPEGImage.Create;
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Image.LoadFromFile(PathToSomeJPEGFile);
    Bmp.Assign(Image);
    FCard.BackGround := Bmp;
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
    Image.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  FCard := TCard.Create(Self);
  FCard.Parent := Self;
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
  // Load a standard image from the backgrounds folder (D2007).
    Bmp.LoadFromFile('C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\CodeGear Shared\Images\BackGrnd\GREENBAR.BMP');
    FCard.BackGround := Bmp;
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;


end.
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. as i have nothing else but a form and a button, and tcard component.  i see a few things i missed. trying to get this working now.